# Expand multiple divs to fit horizontal width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a menu which has three parts to it: 
Menu links left
Images
Menu links right

I need the menu links on the left and right to expand the full width of the screen and the image to be in a div with a fixed width and centered.

So I have the following setup

```
<div class="menuLinks">Some links</div>
<div class="menuImage"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
<div class="menuLinks">Some links</div>
```

And the css

```
.menuLinks{width:100%;float:left;}
.menuImage{width:400px;float:left;}
```

Any help with this is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2zLPF/3/) which is Fully CSS and HTML.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: auto;
}
#block-images{
  background-color: silver;
  width: 400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
.wrapper-menu-left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.wrapper-menu-right{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
.menuBlock{
    text-align: left;
}
#mLeft{
    background-color: green;
    margin-right:200px;
}
#mRight{
    background-color: navy;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-menu-left">
        <div class="menuBlock" id="mLeft">left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-menu-right">
        <div class="menuBlock" id="mRight">right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block-images">images</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously the border and backgrounds are for visibility purposes only :-)

Comment: snap, I should have tested it in Chrome =( I will edit my post.

Comment: +1 for css @Uw was really curious with your idea, it doesn't work with a random sized div, you have to tweak it. Hopefully the OP has one fixed width image there so he can tweak it to his needs ! :D

Comment: The OP stated that the image `div` was going to be fixed. It is possible to put another `div`inside of the `block-images` to scale it down. Yes, you are right, the CSS will have to be tweaked for scaleable images :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is your html menu :

```
<div class="menuLinks" name="links">Some links</div>
<div class="menuImage"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
<div class="menuLinks" name="links">Some links</div>
<div class="menuImage"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
<div class="menuLinks" name="links">Some links</div>
```

Just use css to size menuImages :

```
<style>
.menuImage{width:400px;float:left;}
</style>
```

Use javascript on load to find screen resolution and find each link div size :

```
<script language="javascript">
function resizeMenu()
{
   var linksList = document.getElementsByName('links');
   for(var i = 0; i < linksList.length; i++)
   {
      linksList[i].style.width = (screen.availWidth 
         - 2 * (400) //size of total images)
         / linksList.length; // total number of linksCount
   }
}

resizeMenu();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any possibility of doing this without javascript?

Comment: because you have to set some div size to fixed value and some other size related to window size, the only way is to detect browser resolution on client and then set the elements size;