# How to get an HTML div to dynamically expand in a horizontal direction to fit window width?

Tags: html, css

**Full Source Located At:** http://nounz.if4it.com/Nouns/Applications/A_Application_1.NodeComponent.html

**Problem:** There is an HTML div that is being used for a web page header, ultimately containing a table that has three columns for the left logo, a center title, and a right logo.  I set the div width to "100%" in the CSS statement but the div is not dynamically expanding, in a horizontal direction, to fit the width of the window.

In short, the SVG canvas, further down in the page, requires a wider div and I'd like to get all the other full width divs to expand horizontally to keep things neater.

The div code looks like:

```
  <div class="div_Header">
    <table class="table_Header">
      <tr>
        <td class="td_HeaderLeft"><img src="../../IMAGES/SITE_HEADERS/IF4IT_Logo.png" alt="Header Left Image" /></td>
        <td><img src="../../IMAGES/SITE_HEADERS/Title_Gold_Shadow.png" alt="Header Center Image" /></td>
        <td class="td_HeaderRight"><img src="../../IMAGES/SITE_HEADERS/NOUNZ_Logo_DarkBlueAndGold.png" alt="Header Left Image" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The CSS statement being used is:

```
  div.div_Header {
    width: 100%;
    border:2px solid White;
    border-radius:7px;
    background: WhiteSmoke;
    font: bold 14px Arial;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:WhiteSmoke;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

I've tried adding "**overflow: auto;**" as is recommended in this [other SO post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673588/expand-multiple-divs-to-fit-horizontal-width-of-screen).  However, it doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts on how best to fix the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% DIV width is not really 100%](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344380/100-div-width-is-not-really-100)

Comment: The link you provided does not show any options for how to actually fix the problem, so it's pretty useless other than to explain that 100% div width is not 100%.  What's the fix, to the problem above that actually works?

Comment: Unless you don't have a clue about web development, it's pretty clear that you need to set both `html` and `body` `width` to a 100%.

Comment: I tried that by adding: "**html, body {  margin: 0px;  padding: 0px;  width: 100%;}**" and it failed.  I just republished the new code with this change so you can see, for yourself, that your suggestion does not work.

Comment: A good - and very old - piece of advice. Don't use `tables` for page layout. This was left behind on the mid-90s.

Comment: It turns out that the link you pointed me to wasn't much of an answer, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is partially explained in this article, titled: **"[Using CSS "Display: table-cell" for columns](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/)".**  However, it does not cover the full answer, either.  The code, below, includes the full answer and has been tested.

The first part of the answer is to ensure that the entire html and body envelopes are given a baseline...

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The second part of the answer is to create a full width div that will act as a container for the child divs.  As mentioned in the above article, the containing div should be told to "*act like an HTML table element*" by using the "**display: table;**" attribute...

```
div#div_header_container {
  background: ' + headerBackgroundColor + ';
  border:2px solid ' + 'White' + ';
  border-radius:7px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Third, each of the child divs (in this case there are three) should be given a width that is a percentage of the parent container.  And, since the parent container has been told to act like an HTML table element, these child divs should be told to act like table cells using the "display: table-cell;" attribute.  They should also be set to vertically align their elements in the middle using the "**vertical-align: middle;**" attribute, ensuring that each image in each child div will all align along their middles.

```
div#div_header_left {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius:7px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div#div_header_center {
  width: 60%;
  border-radius:7px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div#div_header_right {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius:7px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Finally, the images that will be located within each child div that acts like a table cell should be decoupled from the divs, themselves and should be given their appropriate alignments...

```
img.image_header_left {
  float: left;
}
img.image_header_center {
  text-align: center;
}
img.image_header_right {
  float: right;
}
```

When applied, the dom's source code will look like:

```
<body>
  <div id="div_header_container">
    <div id="div_header_left">
        <img class="image_header_left" src="./Logo_Left.png" alt="Header Left Image" />
    </div>
    <div id="div_header_center">
        <img class="image_header_center" src="./Logo_Center.png" alt="Header Center Image" />
    </div>
    <div id="div_header_right">
        <img class="image_header_right" src="./Logo_Right.png" alt="Header Right Image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to 0 out the padding and margin on the body element to prevent the browsers native stylesheets from applying those attributes which prevents you from having a true 100% width on your divs:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Well from what I can see on your site this should work, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Absolutely nothing changed.

Comment: I republished the new code, in case you want to see for yourself.

Comment: Got it I misunderstood the issue the first time around. Your problem is caused because of the `width:100%;` set on `div.div_Body`which is setting it to 100% of the width of the body but since it's in a `td` that is in a `tr` with other content it is causing your page to stretch to more than 100% width.